# Bug? Kernel Crash on SparseArray access

Tags: bugs, sparse-arrays, crash

**Bug introduced in 5.2 and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

The following simple code

```
s = SparseArray[{}, {10, 10}]
s[[1, {1, 2, 3, 1, 1}]] = {a, b, c, d, e}
```

on my machine (Windows 8.1 x64, Mathematica 10.0.2) causes the kernel to exit with a beep.

Maybe should be silently handled in some way or at least should report a message and do nothing.

Comment: Hi, I'm on Windows 8.1 x64 with Mathematica 10.0.1, and I have this problem,,, and not only in your case, really ...

Comment: Confirmed in v8.0.4 and v9.0.1, vista 32bit.

Comment: Confirmed in both 7.0.1 and 10.0.2 under Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate because it is in essence the same operation.  If anyone disagrees please let me know, as always.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard did you check that it crashes 6.0? Thing is, it crashes 5.2 as well. Since that's when `SparseArray` was introduced, perhaps it's always been there.

Comment: @Oleksandr No, I can't check v6.  I think it's reasonable to assume that v6 is affected if all others after 5.2 are.

Comment: Confirmed also, it shuts down the kernel (v.10.0.2, OSX10.9.5)

Comment: Sorry @Mr.Wizard for asking again. For some reason I didn't find the other question with my keywords.

Comment: No problem. I always appreciate people searching but I fully understand that searching isn't always effective.